# clojure/jmx with-connection looses connection

Tags: clojure, jmx

I'm trying to call a number of remote JMX operations using the same connection from clojure.  I'm using

```
[org.clojure/java.jmx "0.3.3"]
```

However I'm finding that the connection is eagerly replaced with a local JMX connection.  As an illustration:

given:

```
 (ns test.core
  (:require
    [clojure.java.jmx :as jmx]))
```

If I have something like:

```
(defn caller [col host port]
  (println jmx/*connection*)
  (jmx/with-connection {:host host, :port port :environment
                      {"jmx.remote.credentials" (into-array String ["tomcat" "tomcat"])}}
    (do
    (println jmx/*connection*)
    (map called col))))

(defn called [line]
  (println jmx/*connection*)
)
```

Calling

```
     (caller [1] "host" 8000)
```

I get:

```
#object[com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer 0x2c914364 com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@2c914364]
#object[javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection 0x2b4bbf01 javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector$RemoteMBeanServerConnection@2b4bbf01]
#object[com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer 0x2c914364 com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@2c914364]
```

So the remote connection only lasts for the first statement that accesses connection before being set back to the local server.  How do I keep the remote connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try replacing `(map called col)` with `(run! called col)`, and i bet it would work. This is connected with the clojure's collections laziness: when you call `map`, it returns immediately, without realizing elements, and when it comes to the elements' realization, the flow is already out of `with-connection` block, meaning that function `called` is being called in a context where the connection is already closed.

Comment: if run! does not exist because your using an older version of clojure wrap it in a `dorun`